# Grails Bootstrap plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails-plugin

I read the documentation on grails+bootsrap plugin and also how to customise the bootstrap .less files.
My question is why cant I directly save my css and js under webapp and customise it instead of going through all copy pasting the less files and adding it in resource.groovy and adding lessresource plugin?
Isnt the former option easier.Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just copy-paste, plugins are supposed to do a lot of things easier, but you can still doing it in the "normal" way.

I use grails + bootstrap for some of my applications and I always add my js and css files manually.

Comment: Yup..but I had issues with less resources plugin and again the need to modify or override less files